# How can I map multiple points onto a color gradient along the y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, scatter

My scatter plot values has values between 0 to 1 and I'm trying to plot it in such a way that a certain y-value has a particular color arranged by intensity. For example, in the viridis color map, I want points that are about 0.90 to be Yellow and those around 0.10 to be dark purple. However, I only get these results.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate the data
time = np.arange(50)
a = np.random.random(50)
b = np.ones((50, 50), float)
for t in time: 
    b[i, :] = a

#Creating a color mapping variable
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)

#Generating the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
for t in time:
    ax.scatter(np.ones(len(b[t,:])) * t, b[t, :], c = z, cmap = 'viridis', s = 5, vmin = 0, vmax = 1)

plt.show()
```

This is what my figure looks like:

[image: Scatter plot image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were extremely close. You just have to use the `y` values as the `z` argument with the `viridis` color map. Hence, the only modification you need is `c = b[t, :],`

```
for t in time:
    ax.scatter(np.ones(len(b[t,:])) * t, b[t, :], c = b[t, :], cmap = 'viridis', 
               s = 5, vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Values of one of the axis should be sorted.

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(50)
>>> x.shape
(50,)
>>> y = np.linspace(0,1,50)
>>> y.shape
(50,)
>>> plt.scatter(x,y,c=np.linspace(0,1,50))
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x00000000149AB390>
>>> plt.show()
```